# Has anyone tried using luminescent conjugated oligothiophenes to detect cellulose in a microbial biomass? If so is it accurate?

Tags: microbiology, biochemistry

I recently found this paper http://www.nature.com/articles/srep35578 which describes a "new" method for detecting cellulose. As I'm not an expert in the field I was wondering if other people have used this to detect cellulose in microbial biomass (specifically *E. coli* biofilm) and not just plants. It seems like it should work but maybe I'm missing something.